# ¿Cómo parser estos datos de un Json?

Tags: java, json

¿Me puede decir alguien cómo puedo mostrar el nombre del estadio de este `Json`?

Este es mi `Json`:

```
[ { "Equipo":"Madrid", "estadio":{ "nombre":"ESTO ES EL NOMBRE DEL CAMPO" } } ]
```

Ésta es mi clase:

```
public class Frag_Info_Rafel extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{

SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;

private List<Estadisticas> listJornadas;

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);



    TextView miTexto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mi_java);
    miTexto.setText("INFORMACION RAFELBUÑOL C.F");

    swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
    swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    swipeLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
            android.R.color.holo_green_light,
            android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
            android.R.color.holo_red_light);


    listJornadas = new ArrayList<>();

    getData();

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DecoracionLineaDivisoria(this));

}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {

    if (swipeLayout != null) {
        swipeLayout.setRefreshing( false );
        swipeLayout.destroyDrawingCache();
        swipeLayout.clearAnimation();
    }
}
private void getData(){
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Cargando datos", "Por favor espere...",false,false);

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Config.INFO_RAFEL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    loading.dismiss();

                    parseData(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

private void parseData(JSONArray array){

    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
        Estadisticas info_club = new Estadisticas();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            info_club.setFecha(json.getString(Config.TAG_NOMBRE_EQUIPO));
            info_club.setHora(json.getString(Config.TAG_COMPETICION));
            info_club.setEquipo_Local(json.getString(Config.TAG_TELEFONO));
            info_club.setEquipo_Visitante(json.getString(Config.TAG_CAMISETA));
            info_club.setResultado_Local(json.getString(Config.TAG_PANTALON));
            info_club.setResultado_Visitante(json.getString(Config.TAG_MEDIAS));

            info_club.setEscudo_Local("http://ffcv.es/ncompeticiones/" + (json.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGEN)));



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        listJornadas.add(info_club);
    }

    adapter = new Info_Club_Adapter(listJornadas, this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero obten el jsonArray y dentro los objetos "Equipo" y "estadio", Pero podemos notar que "estadio" tiene internamente un objeto que es "nombre":

```
    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
        String equipo = jsonobject.getString("Equipo");
        JSONObject estadio = jsonobject.getJSONObject("estadio");
        String nombre  = estadio.getString("nombre");
    }
```

Comment: Ese es el que no puedo y el que me hace falta "nombre"

Comment: Listo Rafa he terminado de editar.

Comment: JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr); * En esta linea jsonStr se me queda en rojo ¿de donde sale? y no se arreglarlo. graccias, siempre la primera en responer.

Comment: Elenasys, Gracias por tu ayuda arreglado gracias a ti.

Comment: Que bien que adecuaste el ejemplo a tu necesidad!

Answer (score 0):

La solucion gracias a @Elenasys

> private void parseData(JSONArray array){

```
    for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
        Estadisticas info_club = new Estadisticas();
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = array.getJSONObject(i);

            info_club.setFecha(json.getString(Config.TAG_NOMBRE_EQUIPO));
            info_club.setHora(json.getString(Config.TAG_COMPETICION));
            info_club.setEquipo_Local(json.getString(Config.TAG_TELEFONO));
            info_club.setEquipo_Visitante(json.getString(Config.TAG_CAMISETA));
            info_club.setResultado_Local(json.getString(Config.TAG_PANTALON));
            //info_club.setResultado_Visitante(json.getString(Config.TAG_MEDIAS));

            info_club.setEscudo_Local("http://ffcv.es/ncompeticiones/" + (json.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGEN)));


            JSONObject estadio = json.getJSONObject("estadio");
            info_club.setResultado_Visitante(estadio.getString("nombre"));
```